# Jekyll not auto regenerating on changes to javascript files

Tags: jekyll

My site is regenerating without issues when changes are made to the markup or styles, but when making changes to the javascript it doesn't do anything and I have to reserve the site to pick up changes. Why?

I'm serving the site like so:
`jekyll serve --force_polling --host <my local ip address>`

It's serving a folder with `./css` and `./js` folders as well as a bunch of markup files within.

Comment: How do you run the server? What files are you changing?

Comment: @marcanuy Thanks, I added some more context.

Comment: Did you try without `--force_polling` ? (i.e. `--watch`)

Comment: Check your exclude config variable as well and try to serve with `--incremental`